# Why are there sine and cosine in the magnetic dipole moment (in the torque formula) of a rotating conductor loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, torque, magnetic-moment

I'm trying to redo the textbook example in magnetostatics. The current carrying loop is affected by a magnetic flux in the *ax→* direction. While trying to find the torque on sides *ab* and *cd* for figure c and d, I noticed that they used sine and cosine. Where did the sine and cosine come from?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We prefer that you don't post images of text you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136). Could you edit your post to remove the block of text and math from the image and type it out using quote formatting? If you don't know MathJax syntax, someone can help you out with that.

Comment: @DavidZ I'm zero in programing man, but I'll try after my final exam (its in 4 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your textbook this formula

$\tau=\vec r \times \vec F$

where  $\vec r$ is  sepration vector joining origin to the force vector,
is used to find torque due to forces $\vec F_{ab}$ and $\vec F_{cd}$ respectivaly

torque due to $\vec F_{ab}$

$\vec \tau _{ab}=\vec r_{ab}\times \vec F_{ab}=\left|\dfrac{W}{2}\right|\left( \vec a_{x} sin\theta - \vec a_{y} cos\theta \right)\times |ILB|(\vec{-a_{y}})=-\left|\dfrac{ILBW}{2}\right| sin\theta \ \ \vec a_{z} $

torque due to $\vec F_{cd}$

$\vec \tau _{cd}=\vec r_{cd}\times \vec F_{cd}=\left|\dfrac{W}{2}\right|\left( -\vec a_{x} sin\theta + \vec a_{y} cos\theta \right)\times |ILB|(\vec{a_{y}})=-\left|\dfrac{ILBW}{2}\right| sin\theta \ \ \vec a_{z} $

so, those sines and cosines are due to components of position vector after rotation of loop

**alternative method:**

**background :**

the torque is given by

$\vec{\tau}=\vec M \times \vec B$ where

$\vec M=n I\vec A$ is magnetic moment vector and $B$ is magnetic field vector

but ,

**in your question**: after the loop has rotated by angle $\theta$ about z-axis

now **area vector or normal vector of the loop** (and hence, the magnetic moment vector) is pointing in oblique direction (in x y plane) as shown in figure (d) of your textbook

$\vec M= |IWL|\left(cos\theta  \vec a_{x}+sin\theta \vec a_{y}\right)\   \ \ $     (inside || i've magntiude of that vector)

and $\vec B = |B|\ \vec a_{x}$

therefore,

$\implies \tau=-|IBWL|sin\theta \vec a_{z}\tag{1}$

thus, total torque acting on rectangular loop is given by above expression out of which half part is contributed by side $ab$ and half by side $cd$

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic flux isn't being generated by the entire amount of torque on sides $ab$ and $cd$, the sine and cosine functions are needed to estimate the parts of the sides which do effect it.

Comment: Hi david62225, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This looks like it answers the question, so it would have been inappropriate to post it as a comment. I've edited out the text where you talked about that so the post can be focused on just the answer.